# Возврат ошибок 401 или 403

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему сервер возвращает 403 или 401 ошибки. Я пробовал разные заголовки. Не использовал GUI, но сервер все равно возвращает 401 или 403.

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0";
        string acceptHeaders = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.AddArgument($"user-agent={userAgent}");
        options.AddArgument($"accept={acceptHeaders}");
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.dns-shop.ru");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains("DNS"));
            Console.WriteLine("Page title: " + driver.Title);
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```